# Distance between a polytope and a point

Tags: geometry, optimization, computational-geometry, polytopes

How to calculate the distance between a convex polytope and a point?

Polytope is specified as the solution to the system of linear inequalities.

I'm looking for the method that is computationally efficient.

Comment: Have you considered the methods described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Using QD I can find a point from the polytope which is the closest one to the given point. If this polytope is given by a system of linear equalities then I can use Lagrange Multiplier with multiple constraints to solve QD and this can be done by solving linear system of equations with $n+m$ variables. The complexity of this method is $O((n+m)^{3})$

Comment: Of course instead of QD I should write QP...